# HandleError - how do you display exception message in error page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following on my base controller class which my other controllers inherit from:

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(NotFoundException), View = "NotFound")]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(UnauthorisedException), View = "Unauthorised")]
```

I would like to be able to add the exception message into the view.
So for example when I throw an exception:

```
throw new NotFoundException("This record was not found");
```

I could somehow grab this message and insert it into the NotFound view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception object is send in the `HandleErrorInfo` that is the model of the error page. You can display the exception message with:

```
<%: Model.Exception.Message %>
```

If you want the complete information with the stack trace and everything, you can just use the `ToString` method (which is implicitly called on non-string objects that you output):

```
<%: Model.Exception %>
```